# Save the photo of QR-Code in photo album after scanning it with ZXing using phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova, qr-code, zxing

I am using PhoneGap for Android (2.3.7) to scan a QR Code with the ZXing plugin.

After scanning the code, I couldn't save the taken photo on the phone photo album.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The app (even as a phonegap plugin) does not capture a photo to do its work. It looks at images from the device's preview stream and does not record the images to storage -- this would be very slow. There is not a way to read the images from storage, like via the photo album, since they are never stored there.